# Magento 2 - overriden class extending overriden class not working

Tags: magento2, overrides, dependency-injection, override-block, magento2.3.4

I have overriden the class `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell` with my own `Company\Base\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell`.

The class `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell` extends `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct`.

Now I have overridden `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct` with `\Company\Base\Block\Product\AbstractProduct` and added a new method:

```
public function testAbstractMethod()
{
    echo "test abstract works";
}
```

I added

```
<?php exit($this->testAbstractMethod()) ?>
```

to the template of the class `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell`:

**app\design\frontend\MyTheme\Base\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\list\items.phtml**:

But I get:

> **Invalid method Company\Base\Block\Product\ProductList\Related\Interceptor::testAbstractMethod**

But if I add the method **testAbstractMethod()** to the original core class `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct` then it works.

So it looks like only the first class is getting overriden and if this class extends another class which is overriden by dependency injection, then it wont work and load the original class?

Answer (score 0):

You can't override abstract classes in Magento. You should try with a plugin: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

**EDIT:**
I got it! you have to rename the method. It MUST start with one of: **get**, **set**, **uns** or **has**

So if you rename your method like this:

```
    public function getTestAbstractMethod()
    {
        echo "test abstract works";
    }
```

Will work.

Your exception is thrown in:
**\Magento\Framework\DataObject::__call**

```
     * Set/Get attribute wrapper
     *
     * @param   string $method
     * @param   array $args
     * @return  mixed
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        switch (substr($method, 0, 3)) {
            case 'get':
                $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method, 3));
                $index = isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : null;
                return $this->getData($key, $index);
            case 'set':
                $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method, 3));
                $value = isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : null;
                return $this->setData($key, $value);
            case 'uns':
                $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method, 3));
                return $this->unsetData($key);
            case 'has':
                $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method, 3));
                return isset($this->_data[$key]);
        }
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
            new \Magento\Framework\Phrase('Invalid method %1::%2', [get_class($this), $method])
        );
    }
```

Magento's magic :D

Comment: Thats not an abstract class

Comment: I don't understand. How is renaming the method name helping?

Comment: the method _call check the first 3 characters of the methods, if it not contains that prefixes, throws an exception (take a look on that switch)

Comment: But it has nothing do to with my question?

Comment: i shown you the reason of the exception. The override seems to be working as expected

Comment: No, and if I try it then I get nothing back.

Comment: in your function you need to return the string instead of the echo. Btw if you want to change the behavior of this class you need to plugin the__call method. Otherwise will perform only set get unset and isset operations

Comment: I tried it and it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to simplify the solution. You should do the changes in one class and not override the abstract unless really necessary. You can still override the method from the abstract class in your new class.

Comment: I need to override the AbstractProduct class, since I need the method in every class which extends it.

Comment: Please let me know exactly which method you are trying to override or maybe post the function to understand the issue?

Comment: I don't try to override a method, I try to extend the class

Comment: I think your method contains private method calls but not sure as I don't have the actual method call. Good luck finding a fix for this. I can't keep assuming and replying

Comment: no it is public as you can see in my question.